# How to show all SQLite records for a table in an activity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a sort of debug view for my application that gets all the table names that are in the SQLite database and puts them in a spinner in an activity. When you select a table from the spinner it should replace a fragment in the layout displaying all the records for that table.

Currently I am creating a table row then adding a text view for each column of the record, then appending the row to a table in the layout but this seems to be taxing on a tablet. It works fine for tables with just a few records but crashes with OutOfMemory error in logcat on tables that have plenty of records.

I considered using an adapter that utilizes view recycling but unsure how to approach that since I can never be sure the exact amount of columns for each table. What would be the optimal way to display this much information? Here is the code I am currently using:

```
private void getRecords() {
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                TableRow.LayoutParams textViewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(350, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                textViewParams.setMargins(25, 25, 25, 25);
                textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
                textView.setText(cursor.getString(i));
                row.addView(textView);
            }
            table.addView(row);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your gradle file.

make your memory larger:

```
    minHeapSize = '512m'
    maxHeapSize = '5120m'
```